# Elegir que cantidad de core deseo utilizar

Tags: java, hilos

Me podría ayudar en algo, necesito ejecutar este código pero eligiendo que cantidad de core deseo utilizar de mi pc, esto es para determinar el tiempo de búsqueda, para mi caso tengo cuatro core y necesito mirar que tiempo se demora en buscar un archivo.

Gracias

```
package buscarfichero;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class BuscarFichero {


public static void main (String[] args) {
    BuscarFichero objBuscarFichero = new BuscarFichero();
    String fichero = "";
    String directorio = "";

     fichero =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el nombre del fichero:");
     directorio =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nDirectorio de inicio de la busqueda: ");
    int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    System.out.println (availableProcessors);

    objBuscarFichero.buscar (fichero, new File(directorio));
}

public void buscar (String argFichero, File argFile) {
    File[] lista = argFile.listFiles();

    if (lista != null) {
        for (File elemento : lista) {
            if (elemento.isDirectory()) {
                buscar (argFichero, elemento);
            } else if (argFichero.equalsIgnoreCase(elemento.getName())) {
                System.out.println (elemento.getParentFile());

            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: si no creas ningun *thread* todo el codigo se ejecuta en el *thread* principal, usando solo un *core* de la CPU. ¿Que quieres hacer, medir cuanto demora?, ¿Paralelizar el trabajo en varios *threads*?, ¿Medir cuanto demora en varios *threads*?

Comment: Hola, deseo buscar un archivo en mi pc, en cualquiera ubicación pero la busqueda  se  debe realizar especificando, por parte del usuario, el número de Core(s) con la/los cual(es) desea realizarla, con esto busco unas estadísticas de tiempo.Gracias